# How can I import the *.xcodeproj of React Native framework into my native project elegantly?

Tags: reactjs, native

I have already had a native iOS  project,
and now my leader let me use react native to build UI in it, just use JavaScript to create two platform Apps.

The normal steps to init a react native project is use the command `react-native init XXXX`, however, the initialized project is an new project. I have to import the *.xcodeproj of React Native framework into my native project and I don't want to drag the project files into my previous project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the method to solve my problem:
Open the URL https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

- Create a new package.json file
- Install node_modules with command npm install --verbose in terminal
- Create Podfile at the same path of native project, so that can import the *.xcodeproj of ReactNative as the native project submudles.